# How to format a date in a given timezone in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have an ISO timestamp with a timezone:

```
> let datestring = "2016-07-15T09:20:32.730689-04:00";
```

I'd like to format it to a human-readable format like "Jul 15 2016, 09:20" while keeping the timezone.

I tried this first:

```
> new Date(datestring).toString()
"Fri Jul 15 2016 15:20:32 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
> new Date(datestring).toISOString()
"2016-07-15T13:20:32.730Z"
```

Of course this can't do what I wanted because `new Date()` only stores milliseconds since epoch and the `-04:00` timezone was dropped after parsing. Okay.

I also learned that:

- `toString()` formats using w/r/t my local timezone, with a format similar to `asctime`,
- `toISOString()` formats w/r/t UTC with a format from ISO 8601.

Neither looks helpful, so let's look into the libraries.

---

Next thing I tried was `moment`:

```
> moment(datestring)._tzm
-240
```

okay, Moment doesn't lose my date's timezone! That's nice, I hope I can use a `moment` object like an aware `datetime` object in Python. So how do I format it?

```
> moment(datestring).toString()
"Fri Jul 15 2016 15:20:32 GMT+0200"
> moment(datestring).toISOString()
"2016-07-15T13:20:32.730Z"
```

Oh, these look like Moment just forwarded the request to the datetime. Let's try something then:

```
moment(datestring).format("MMM D YYYY, HH:mm")
"Jul 15 2016, 15:20"
```

The format looks nice but what's this 15:20? Oh, that's my local time. Looks like `format()` also assumes that I wanted to ignore the datetime's parsed timezone offset and I'd prefer my local timezone. No luck here.

But there's `moment().utcOffset` that allows me to specify a given timezone offset:

```
> let m = moment(datestring)
> m.utcOffset(m._tzm).format("MMM D YYYY, HH:mm")
"Jul 15 2016, 09:20"
```

Yay, it works! However I didn't see this `_tzm` documented anywhere, looks like I'm messing with `moment` internals now.

---

What's the "by the book" way to achieve this?

Could this be done in vanilla js without `moment`, assuming I'm fine with `iso` format?

Comment: It's hard to do this in vanilla js. Have you seen [moment timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)? That would probably be helpful.

Comment: I normally use `moment-timezone` when I want to be able to say "show this date as in US/Eastern". This is a different case: I already have a timestamp with desired timezone offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`parseZone`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/) function:

```
let datestring = "2016-07-15T09:20:32.730689-04:00";
let m = moment.parseZone(datestring);

m.hour();                      // 9
m.format("MMM D YYYY, HH:mm"); // "Jul 15 2016, 09:20"
```

By default moment will use the local time zone, but if you use `parseZone` then it will use the input string's time zone.